# how to calculate the height of an element on document.ready?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, user-experience

I have a directive which is for an sticky sidebar, everything is OK on the top of the page, the issue I have is on the footer, I need to do something that dynamically catches the height of the screen or the screen resolution

this my directive

```
.directive('sticky', function($document, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {

      var width = $document.width();

      if (width > 991) {
        $timeout(function() {
          angular.element($document).ready(function() {
            var stickySidebar = element,
                stickyHeight,
                sidebarTop,
                scrollTop,
                stickyStop,
                sidebarBottom,
                stopPosition;

            if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
              stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
              sidebarTop = stickySidebar.offset().top;
            }

            $document.scroll(function() {

              if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
                scrollTop = $document.scrollTop() + 52; //stkicy responds to the navbar
                if (sidebarTop < scrollTop) {
                  stickySidebar.css('top', scrollTop - sidebarTop);
                  sidebarBottom = stickySidebar.offset().top + stickyHeight;
                  stickyStop = $('.main-content').offset().top + $('.main-content').height();
                  if (stickyStop < sidebarBottom) {
                    stopPosition = $('.main-content').height() - stickyHeight;
                    stickySidebar.css('top', stopPosition);
                  }
                }
                else {
                  stickySidebar.css('top', '0');
                }
              }
            });

            $document.resize(function() {
              if (stickySidebar.length > 0) {
                stickyHeight = stickySidebar.height();
              }
            });
          });

        }, 1000);

      }else {
        console.log('do not apply function because the size is not the proper one');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

look at the image here, this is the proper behavior but in a very big resolution screen, as you can see the red label below is the margin that I want to give to every resolution screen

[image]

and this is the one in 13" laptop

[image]

as you can see there is no margin so the Sticky element on the left doesn't work if it is the same height of the screen, I want to give that same margin on every single resolution as in the first image, how can I do that with my directive ?

Comment: This has to be on document.ready? can't be on window.load?

Comment: ok yes, but how can I do it ?@ntgCleaner

Comment: no point using `ready` in an angular directive.link function won't run until element exists in the first place and angular itself won;t be manipulating the DOM until after `ready` also